# Событие mousewheel листает по несколько слайдов как сделать что б листало по одному

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, owl-carousel, mousewheel

есть слайдер который реагирует на колесо мыши
но почти постоянно он крутит по несколько слайдов
как исправить?

Пример взял из документации совы карусели https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html

А вот и сам слайдер http://dten.pokt.store/

Пожалуйста подскажите как сделать что б листался строго 1 слайд

Comment: Проблема решена https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515446/jquery-mousewheel-detecting-when-the-wheel-stops/3515490#3515490